# What is __aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr1' and how can I avoid it?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I have a bunch of arm assembly, C and C++ files. gcc is trying to link them, but these are for an embedded project.

I am not using any external libraries, all code that is being used was written by me. An error seems to happen because I have a function called `int kernel_main(void)` defined in `main.c` that is trying to call `set_LED(int value)` defined in `mailbox.cpp` which includes the header `mailbox.h` (I did include the header in the main.c file).

The exact error is:

```
undefined reference to `__aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr1'
```

The way I am making my project is:
-compile all source files (.s, .c, .cpp) into object files (.o) without linking (-c), then link them all together with the use of a custom linker script.

Edit: I am going to add some information to make things more clear.

First changing all files so that all of them are C files (no cpp extensions) yields:

```
undefined reference to `set_LED'
```

It is unlikely that the issue itself is name mangling an it probably has nothing to do with CPP and C differences.

The problem is very likely to be a linker issue

This is the build process:

Compile c files, Example:

```
arm-none-eabi-g++ -O0 -march=armv8-a source/MainFiles/mailbox.cpp -nostartfiles -c -o objects/MainFiles/mailbox.o
```

(Compiling a C++ file would be identical except for the use of g++ instead of gcc)

Link everything:

```
arm-none-eabi-ld object1 object2... -o build/kernel.elf -T ./source/kernel.ld -I include_directory_1 -I include_directory_2 -L include_directory_1 -L indlude_directory_2
```

Include directories are all directories under the current one

Edit:
The error came back. Ignore the parts of this question relevant to name mangling. The error I need to fix is:

```
./objects/Hardware/mailbox.o:(.ARM.exidx+0x18): undefined reference to `__aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr1'
```

So far all I know is that this has something to do with unwinding the stack and exceptions. It seems the function is defined in libgcc. However I have used `-nostdlib`, I have omitted it, and in both cases the error persists. I have tried changing file extensions to .c whenever possible and to .cpp whenever possible, alas the error is always there.

It got fixed only as long as I had exactly 1 cpp file and the rest of my files were C files (this is no longer true, I tried). What triggered the error again was that I was refactoring the code and I wanted to move a couple of functions to new files.

In other words, without deleting a single file, declaring a function named `wait(uint32_t time)` in mailbox.cpp works, declaring it in a file called time.c (or cpp) with it's respective header declaration and including the header in mailbox.cpp breaks things. Note I don't delete the files when moving the function I simply delete the function declaration inside each file.

Adding a stub like this:

```
void __aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr1()
{

}
```

Fixes the problem and the code works. But I don't like this solution. I don't want a useless stub being called mysteriously in my code. I don't need nor want this function in my current implementation, how can I tell the compiler or the linker that they are to omit whatever they are doing that requires this function?

Comment: Just a guess, but the `unwind` part sounds like it's part of the implementation of exceptions.

Comment: I swear to the god of coding I am not using exceptions explicetely though

Comment: Have you read this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27831735/cross-compile-glibc-for-arm-got-undefined-reference-to-some-unwind-functions ?

Comment: Yes, and adding -lgcc_eh. doesn't seem to do anything for me

Comment: I don't know if gcc still supports `-fno-exceptions` but if it does, you could try compiling with that so it doesn't put in unwinding code in case e.g. a constructor throws an exception.

Comment: Adding the flag -static-libstdc++  didn't help. in fact I suspect I have a problem in my included -I and -L. The original error seems to be gone after adding some extra -L directories and now I only get  a set_LED not found error

Comment: You may get better results using g++ as the linker instead of ld

Comment: does g++ accept ld scripts in it's arguments?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution is very simple. As it turns out exceptions are enabled by default (which is what generates the code that calls `__eabi_unwind_cpp_pr1`). To disable them all that is needed is to pass:
`-fno-exceptions` as an argument to the gcc/g++ compiler and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

You have a reference to this function that belongs to the C++ runtime of GCC. It's part of the exception handling. Whatever you are doing, sounds a little crazy, but anyway you can do this if you really know what you are doing. You must link against the C++ runtime libraries. That's it. Link against "libstdc++".

About the `set_LED` I also believe it's just about the C++ mangling, just as Justin J mentioned in the other answer.

Comment: Is this a "compiler defined" library, or an actual library? The thing is, this is for an embedded project, so there is no OS, and if this is related to exception handling, that sounds like it needs an OS

Comment: no, it doesn't need nothing from the OS for the exception handling... you are using some code that is calling for exceptions handling for sure. Behind the scenes `throw` is nothing more than a function that starts the stack unwind process. This function, as the name suggests, has something to do with the unwind process. It's hard to tell exactly, once it's GCC specific. I would suggest you to take a look at this link: https://monoinfinito.wordpress.com/series/exception-handling-in-c/

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this when mixing C and C++.  Because of name mangling, the symbols will have different names internally depending on the type of the source file.

If the source for 'set_LED'is a c file, use the following in the header around the prototype and see if it helps.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

// function prototypes here

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: source for set_LED is a cpp file

Answer (score -2):

Please also add prefix "-shared" without quotes to -fno-exceptions. I am using ARM GCC version

Comment: What does it do and why should it be added?