# How i can build my project using arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ for AArch32 with glibc 2.17

Tags: c++, arm, debian, cross-compiling

How i can build my project using arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ for AArch32 with glibc 2.17?
On debian x64.

I tried crosstool-ng but this not have old glibc versions.
I tired compile glibc 2.18 but compiler give errors like this:

```
/root/glibc-2.18/build-arm/libc_pic.os: In function `_Unwind_Resume':
find_exidx.c:(.text+0x534): undefined reference to `libgcc_s_resume'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
../Makerules:577: recipe for target '/root/glibc-2.18/build-arm/libc.so' failed
make[2]: *** [/root/glibc-2.18/build-arm/libc.so] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/root/glibc-2.18/elf'
Makefile:236: recipe for target 'elf/subdir_lib' failed
make[1]: *** [elf/subdir_lib] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/glibc-2.18'
Makefile:9: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Can you add minimal code to reproduce? Did you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27831735/cross-compile-glibc-for-arm-got-undefined-reference-to-some-unwind-functions and use `-lgcc_eh`?